# Issue with time conversion in LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes

I am using below code to add an appointment to the recipients calendar.
It works fine for India users. But when users from other timezone add the appointment it is not getting converted to local time.

Can any one help ?

### Code below

```vb
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    Dim session As New notessession
    Dim workspace As New notesuiworkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim mailDoc As notesdocument

    Dim mailDB As NotesDatabase
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strLocation As String
    Dim strStartTime As String
    Dim strEndTime As String
    Dim userName As New NotesName(session.UserName)

    Set uidoc=workspace.CurrentDocument
    Set doc=uidoc.document



    '**********Please modify this section before sending********
    strTitle="Test"
    strDate="11SEPTEMBER2014"
    strLocation="BLR"
    strStartTime="10:05"
    strEndTime="10:20"
    '************************************************************************

    Set mailDB=session.CurrentDatabase
    Set mailDoc=mailDB.CreateDocument

    Set startTime=New NotesDateTime(strDate & " - " & strStartTime & " IST")
    Set endTime=New NotesDateTime(strDate & " - " & strEndTime & " IST")
    mailDoc.StartTimeZone="Z=-3005$DO=0$ZX=35$ZN=India"
    mailDoc.EndTimeZone="Z=-3005$DO=0$ZX=35$ZN=India"   
    mailDoc.Form="Appointment"
    mailDoc.AppointmentType="0"
    mailDoc.Location=strLocation
    mailDoc.Subject=strTitle
    mailDoc.Principal=userName.Common
    Dim currItem As NotesItem
    Set currItem=mailDoc.AppendItemValue("StartDate", startTime)
    Set currItem=mailDoc.AppendItemValue("StartDate", startTime)
    Set currItem=mailDoc.AppendItemValue("EndDate", endTime)
    Set currItem=mailDoc.AppendItemValue("StartTime", startTime)
    Set currItem=mailDoc.AppendItemValue("EndTime", endTime)
    Set currItem=mailDoc.AppendItemValue("StartDateTime", startTime)
    Set currItem=mailDoc.AppendItemValue("EndDateTime", endTime)
    Set currItem=mailDoc.AppendItemValue("CalendarDateTime", startTime)
    '*********Popup for the Alarm***************
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Alarms","1")
    Call mailDoc.replaceitemvalue("$Alarm",1)
    Call mailDoc.replaceitemvalue("$AlarmOffset",-120)
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("$AlarmUnit", "M")
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("$IconSwitcher", |Reminder|)
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("$AlarmMemoOptions", "")
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("dispAlarms","1")
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("dispAlarmsRd","1")
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("HideFromCalendar", "1")

    '******************************End popup********
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("_ViewIcon",158)  
    Set currItem=doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
    Call currItem.CopyItemToDocument(mailDoc,"Body")    
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("SequenceNum","1")
    Call mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("$CSVersion",|2|) 
    Call mailDoc.ComputeWithForm(True, True)
    Call mailDoc.Save(True, False)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set uidoc= workspace.EditDocument(True,mailDoc) 
    Set csEventObj= New CSCalendarEntry( 1, mailDoc, uidoc )
    Call csEventObj.SetUIFlag( UI_FLAG_ALARM )  
    Call csEventObj.QueryClose( Continue)
    Call csEventObj.QuerySave( True)    
    Call csEventObj.PostSave()  
    On Error Goto 0
    ''Call uidoc.Close(True)

    ''Dim var
    ''var=Messagebox("Calendar Entry added.", 0, "Mail Db")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at a meeting created manually, you'll see that StartDateTime contains a date and time, but StartDate contains just the date, and StartTime contains just the time. That's not how you've done it here, and I suspect that's your problem.
Also, use ReplaceItemValue, not AppendItemValue, to set a field. And I see you set the same field more than once (which, since you were using the wrong method, made it multivalued).